# replacing string integer in list, python

Tags: python, string, arraylist, integer

I wanted to replace string with an integer so I first tried this

```
timeupseats=[0,480,480,0]
for n in range(0,4): 
   if timeupseats[n]==0:
       timeupseats[n]='CLOSED'
for n in range(0,4): 
   if timeupseats[n]=='CLOSED':
       timeupseats[n]==0
```

Because the first code didn't work, I tried this code for the second time and it worked

```
timeupseats=[0,480,480,0]
for n in range(0,4): #print closed when there is no ticket left
    if timeupseats[n]==0:
        timeupseats[n]='CLOSED'
timeupseats = [0 if i=='CLOSED' else i for i in timeupseats]
```

What's the difference between the first code and the second code?
Why did only the second code work?

Answer (score 1):

In your first set of code you have this error on the last line :
`timeupseats[n]==0`

You want to set it to `0 (=)` not check for equality `(==)`

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to to this. The in my opinion the most robust one would be to first define the values you want to replace, then apply that on each element of the list with ‘map’:

```
# make some data
ls = list(range(10))
# define values to replace
mapping = {0: 'CLOSED'}
# do replacement 
ls = list(map(lambda x: mapping.get(x, x), ls))
print(ls)
```

There is also the more explicit, but more difficult to maintain way:

```
ls = list(range(10))
for i, x in enumerate(ls):
    if x == 0:
        ls[i] = 'CLOSED'

print(ls)
```

Comment: User all ready created `ls` which is equal to `['CLOSED', 480, 480, 'CLOSED']` for input `[0,480,480,0]` , but user is try to get back initial stage

Comment: Then just edit the mapping :). I let you figure it out and edit my answer in about 30min.

Comment: In questioner last line of code snippet `timeupseats[n]==0` instead of `comparison`, it should be `assign`

Comment: Create a extra logic for that input `ls` to get back to initial stage

Comment: Everything is okk with your both logic :)